# Stop Windows Domain Environment Caching Old Passwords?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cache

I have noticed on my domain environment; the old Administrator password (before password expire).. The client machines have cached the old password and have the ability to bypass the new password by entering the old one..?

Basically; I'm running a UAC enabled domain, which needs the administrator password to continue basic stuff; installations and such. The password for the administrator account has been changed due to expiration of said accounts password. By accident a fellow administrator typed the old password and still bypassed the UAC with what should have been the incorrect password.

Is this a bug with the environment? or something that needs to be tweaked in the server sided settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your situation is, but I see two possibilities.

### 1. You have cached domain credentials

In this case, it's working as designed.  Windows will remember the last X logins in th event that a machine needs to be accessed, but a domain controller is unavailable.  I think it's five by default, but you can turn this feature off with a GPO.

It's under <kbd>Computer Configuration</kbd> --> <kbd>Windows --> Settings</kbd> --> <kbd>Security Settings</kbd> --> <kbd>Local Policies</kbd> -->  <kbd>Security Options</kbd> and the policy is named `Network Access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication`.  Enable it, and no more password caching.

Though, this will cause issues if you need to access a machine that's orphaned from the domain, so keep those local Administrator account passwords handy.

### 2. Your users are using the local Administrator account

Also working as designed - password expiration only applies to *domain* accounts, not local ones.

Fortunately, this can also be handled with GPOs.  You'd want to disable or [rename the local administrator account](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc747484%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and change the password, which is also doable.  The location of the various default GPOs for configuring the local administrator account are below.

> In Group Policy Object Editor, click Computer Configuration, click Windows Settings, click Security Settings, click Local Policies, and then click Security Options.

I find it easiest to disable the Administrator account, with the GPO and deploy a new account with local permissions with GPP (`Local Users and Groups` under `Computer Preferences`, `Control Panel`), but the way you do it is up to you.

Comment: Basically; I'm running a UAC enabled domain, which needs the administrator password to continue basic stuff; installations and such. The password for the administrator account has been changed due to expiration of said accounts password. By accident a fellow administrator typed the old password and still bypassed the UAC with what should have been the incorrect password. ---- I will try this tomorrow when at the office; I will inform and make the necessary upvote + mark as question if resolved

Comment: @DarylGill  Might be worth editing that into your question, as well as anything else you learn tomorrow, especially if this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Problem resolved with the policy!